# Gravar Array de Telefone no Banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, .net-core

Criei uma tabela de `Clientes` e duas a partir de clientes que são `ClientesTelefone` e `ClientesEmail` no meu formulário estou gerando campos de email e telefone dinamicamente, então gostaria de saber como posso receber e gravar esses valores nas tabelas, poderiam me ajudar por favor ??

`ApplicationClient`: aqui crio o cliente.

```
public async Task<ApplicationClient> CreateClientAsync(ApplicationClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _context.Clientes.AddAsync(client);

            if (result.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return result.Entity;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

ClientController:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Não é possível carregar o usuário com o ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            var client = new ApplicationClient {
                TipoPessoa = model.TypePerson,Nome = model.Name,
                RazaoSocial = model.CompanyName, NomeFantasia = model.FantasyName,
                Cpfj = model.Cpfj, CEP = model.CEP, UF = model.UF,
                Bairro = model.Neighborhood, Cidade = model.City,
                Endereco = model.Address, Numero = model.Number,
                Complemento = model.Complement, InfoAdicionais = model.AddInformation,
                DataNascimento = model.BirthDate, UsuarioId = user.Id
            };

            var result = await _clientManager.CreateClientAsync(client);

            var clientTelephone = new ApplicationClientTelephone
            {
                Telefone = model.Telephone

            };

            var clientEmail = new ApplicationClientEmail
            {
                Email = model.Email
            };

            TempData["MensagemSucesso"] = "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso";

            return View("Index");
        }
```

ApplicationClient:

```
public class ApplicationClient
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public Guid UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationClientTelephone> ClientesTelefone { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationClientEmail> ClientesEmail { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Usuario { get; set; }

}
```

Possuo `ApplicationClientTelephone` E `ApplicationClientEmail`.

Gostaria que depois que o cliente fosse adicionado, começasse a gerar uma reação em cadeia que adicionaria os telefone e os emails do cliente.

se conseguirem me ajudar agradeço muito.

Comment: Como está o mapeamento das suas entidades? Se possível edite a pergunta e coloque elas para verificar, geralmente no mapeamento estiver correto e já conter no cliente a lista de email e telefone já irá em cadeia adicionar no banco de dados.

Comment: Resposta Editada amigo.

Comment: É que no caso, o usuário pode adiciona apenas `n` telefones, dessa forma teria que ter um loop adicionando os telefones não sei se me entendeu

Comment: Respondi a pergunta e adicionei duas maneiras para inserir telefone e email, uma com loop e uma com apenas 1 item em cada lista

Answer (score 0):

Antes dessa Chamada adicione os telefones e emails na lista

```
var result = await _clientManager.CreateClientAsync(client);
```

O código deve ficar próximo a isso

```
clientTelephone.ClientesTelefone = new List<ApplicationClientTelephone>(){
   new ApplicationClientTelephone
   {
      Telefone = model.Telephone
   }
};

clientTelephone.ClientesEmail = new List<ApplicationClientEmail>(){
   new ApplicationClientEmail
   {
      Email = model.Email
   }
};

var result = await _clientManager.CreateClientAsync(client);
```

Caso deseje adicionar mais de um email ou telefone deverá efetuar um for e chamar o método Add() das listas para ir adicionando os itens, pressupondo que model.Email e model.Telefone sejam listas.

```
clientTelephone.ClientesTelefone = new List<ApplicationClientTelephone>();
clientTelephone.ClientesEmail = new List<ApplicationClientEmail>();

foreach(var telefone in model.Telefone)
{
    clientTelephone.ClientesTelefone.Add(new ApplicationClientTelephone() { Telefone = telefone });
}

foreach(var email in model.Email)
{
    clientTelephone.ClientesEmail.Add(new ApplicationClientEmail() { Email = email });
}

var result = await _clientManager.CreateClientAsync(client);
```

Comment: `new <ApplicationClientEmail>{}` ?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo corrigi, como estou digitando fora do visual studio acabei esquecendo do List<>

Comment: Não criei os dados como lista ainda, apenas tentei receber do formulario html, pesquisando na internet achei alguns exemplos utilizando `string[] values = Request.Form.GetValues("textBoxes");` estou tentando adaptar a sua solução ao meu problema